# Retrieve data from filled-form then save into database and then display in table form DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django, database

I am relatively new to Django. I would like to save data from a filled-form, which is the data being filled into timesheet.html into Database then retrieve data and display it into a table which is list_timetable.html. But I am stuck and will get attribute error on views.py "query_results = ltimesheet.objects.all()".

timesheet.html

```
{% extends 'hrfinance/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Timesheet {% endblock %}
{% block link %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'hrfinance/css/timesheet.css' %}"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*to ensure that all the textbox and checkbox have been filled before users can submit*/
    function validation() {
        /*ensure start date has been entered*/
        if (!$('#sdate').val().trim()) {
            alert('Please fill in start date field');
        }
        /*ensure end date has been entered*/
        if (!$('#edate').val().trim()) {
            alert('Please fill in end date field');
        }
        /*ensure checkbox has been ticked*/
        if (!$('#agree').is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please indicate that you have satisfied all the requirements');
        }
        else{
            console.log('ok')
      }
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="sub-bar">
    <p>Submit Timesheet</p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="sub-content">
            <div>
                <p>Start Date: {{timesheet.startDate}}</p>
                <input id="sdate" type="date" name="startdate">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-content">
            <div>
                <p>End Date: {{timesheet.endDate}}</p>
                <input id="edate" type="date" name="enddate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="end-content">
        <div class="center-align">
            <div class="checklist">
                <p>By checking this box I agree that I have satisfied all requirements to continue receiving my scholarship
            allowance.</p>
                <input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="tick-att">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="align-right">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" >
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</from>
{% endblock %}
```

list_timesheet.html - used to display data in table

```
{% block body %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    { % for item in query_results % }
    <tr>
        <td>{{ltimesheet.timesheet}}</td>
        <td>{{ltimesheet.status}}</td>
    </tr>
    { % end for % }
</table>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Timesheet, LTimesheet, Application, Scholarship

def ltimesheet(request):
query_results = ltimesheet.objects.all()
return render(request, 'hrfinance/list_timesheet.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

#consists of all the details in the timesheet
class Timesheet(models.Model):
studentID = models.CharField("Student ID", max_length=8, primary_key=True, default="")
studentName = models.CharField("Student Name", max_length=500, default="")
startDate = models.DateField("Start Date", max_length=8)
endDate = models.DateField("End Date", max_length=8)

def __str__(self):
    return self.studentID

#consists of all the details of the timesheet under 'View Timesheets'        

class LTimesheet(models.Model):
timesheet = models.ForeignKey(Timesheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.CharField("Status", max_length=100)
```

Comment: Can you add complete error message

Answer (score 0):

This is because python is case sensitive and you are using function name (ltimesheet) instead of model name(LTimesheet), and also to render data you need to pass them to your html file

Change your views.py file to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Timesheet, LTimesheet, Application, Scholarship

def ltimesheet(request):
    query_results = LTimesheet.objects.all()
    data={query_results:query_results}
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/list_timesheet.html',data)
```

Comment: to save data from timesheet.html into database, how do i do that ? what should i add in views.py ?     def timesheet(request):
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/timesheet.html')         like this ?

Comment: My answer is for fetching and presenting the data if you want to store data from html to modal you need to pass the data in a form with csrf token and in views.py you can receive data using request.POST.get('inputname') and you can use Modelname.objects.create(inputname=inputname) for creating record